# Qmetry manual and automation testing

Tags: automation, jira, manual-testing

Currently I'm using manual and selenium automation testing. I just want to know that using Qmetry with JIRA will helpful for both manual and automation testing. What type of benefits I'll get using Qmerty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, it is going to be a good approach to both your manual and automation testing plans. Some of the benefits it will help you yield include:

1. Improved test management (cloning, authoring, reusing, etc.)
2. Cross-project reporting
3. Seamless integrations with ready-made CI/CD tools
4. You can create, retain, and manage your test assets versions
5. Exploratory testing can be done with automated test case documentation
6. Above all, it can help you reduce your test efforts.

Answer (score 1):

We are using QMetry Test Management for Jira (QTM4J) from 3 years and we are very satisfied. The app has excellent UI/UX with good features, very fast and responsive support. In my view QTM4J is the most economical test management app inside Jira that supports manual, exploratory, and automated testing capabilities. It enables QA teams to efficiently manage all testing activities with a single tool and provides actionable insights, enabling them to release better quality software faster.

- Manual testers can author, maintain, execute test cases & save test results & attachments, log bugs and link test cases to stories for complete traceability and adequate test coverage.
- QTM4J supports industry most popular automation frameworks like Test NG, Junit, Cucumber, QAF, UFT, Robot, Spec flow, PyTest. Automation Testers can import their automation test results to QTM4J using simple one call automation api or through Jenkins or maven repo. We are using QAS and it integrates seamlessly with QTM4J.
- QTM4J has some best in class inbuilt system reports, that can be fetched cross projects, filtered on custom fields and exported to excel.

Answer (score 0):

- Authoring, cloning, reusability, and linkages inside Jira with Native BDD Support
- Cross-project reporting with dashboard gadgets and Confluence integration
- Scalable and flexible with ready-made integrations for CI/CD tools, Open REST APIs
- Automated test case documentation with Exploratory Testing
- Create, retain, and manage versions of your test assets
- Minimize testing efforts with Test Data Parameterization
- Awesome and highly rated product support team
- Granular user and group-level permissions to ensure secured use

For trial
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215144/qmetry-for-jira-test-management?hosting=cloud&tab=overview